# SQL Server table's Column has date time value but in unrecognizable format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016 and have a table with one of the column datatype as BIGINT but its value is **1586862000000**

This is not directly recognizable as DateTime value as datatype is also BIGINT, but the name of the column is PREV_EXEC_TIME which gives a hint that value is in DateTime but somewhat in encrypted form plus my guess is 15 stands for 3 pm as I had executed query at 15:00

So my concern is how can I convert this value to a standard DateTime format whenever I query (SELECT)on it

Is there some function like cast or convert to get expected output?

Comment: Your first step needs to speak with whoever else uses this field and find out how they interpret it, what documentation exists, etc. The 15 may represent 3 PM (but in what timezone?), but the rest of the number is not recognizable as any part of a time except for maybe seconds.

Comment: Many and twisted are the ways mortals have devised to store date and time values as integers. If you don't know what the client code is doing, do yourself a favor and *do not guess*, nor ask others to guess; it is very easy to get it wrong, and even a difference of one hour can invalidate your results. `SELECT DATEADD(second, 1586862000000 / 1000.0, '19700101')` gives me `2020-04-14 11:00:00.000`, which looks close enough to a valid time that this is almost certainly a time in milliseconds, *probably* using the UNIX epoch, but I can't tell if it's actually in UTC or in another timezone.

Comment: @JeroenMostert my bad I forgot to mention its PST Zone and your query generated correct date. But time is not correct may be due to timezone. So since its PST, I am expecting time value as 3 and can you please help in explaining why you divided 1586862000000 with 1000.0 ?

Comment: Because `DATEADD` doesn't accept values that don't fit in an `INT`, so I reduced the precision to seconds to make it work. How did I know it's in milliseconds? Just a guess as the value looked too big to be anything else. Again, if you want to do yourself a favor you'll need to actually find out what the client code is storing and why. It might be offsetting or rounding the value itself already, for example, and it's important to know that to get the correct local time.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Unix timestamp in milliseconds.  If you are content with second-level precision, you can use:

```
select dateadd(second, 1586862000000 / 1000, '1970-01-01')
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support `dateadd_big()`, but you can add the milliseconds separately if those are needed:

```
select dateadd(millisecond, 1586862000000 % 1000, dateadd(second, 1586862000000 / 1000, '1970-01-01'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon your query generated correct date. But time is not correct may be due to timezone. So since its PST, I am expecting time value as 3 and can you please help in explaining why you divided 1586862000000 with 1000.0 ?

Comment: That converts from milliseconds to seconds.  The resulting time is always UTC.  You'll need to convert it if you want it in local time.